# Free Fast converion of html/css to pdf using php only

Tags: php, html, pdf, converters

I have multiple rich html pages with css which I need to convert to pdf, so far **mPDF** is converting accurately which is basically taking 3sec to convert a single document I have almost 100 documents to convert at the same. **Conversion is too slow!**

Note: html can not be modified.

I would like to know if there is good free php library which I can use.

Looking at [this whole list](http://bhavinrana.blogspot.com/2013/04/convert-html-css-to-pdf-with-php.html#.UYs88MqUJZc) is not worthing here

Comment: What's the actual problem? You already have a working library

Comment: The time: min 3sec each doc*100

Comment: So you run a background process to do the task, don't do it from a web browser while a user is waiting for a response

Comment: yes, I'm not archiving them, they are downloadable, and there is huge database. In most scenario user select and download 100 docs at a time!

Comment: Why then not caching documents? Just check if the HTML page has changed and if not, serve the copy.

Comment: In that case, run as a background process, and email to the user once they're all converted and bundled into a zip; or cache already converted documents as Voitcus has suggested

Comment: Sounds like I need to make a cron job

Comment: Even so, you would need this once just to prepare cached copies or each time when document(s) change. You don't need to run cron job on each user request.